# Eclipse does not recognize Gradle dependencies, despite "Update Dependencies" returning success

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependency-management, gradle-plugin

I'm using the Gradle STS plugin (version 3.7.3) for Eclipse (version 4.5.2), on Kubuntu 15.10.  I use a bunch of dependencies, but Eclipse does not recognize any one of them, treating them as not found.  At seemingly random intervals, I get this error once for each of my nested projects:

```
java.io.File cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration
Could not fetch model of type 'StsEclipseProject' using Gradle distribution
'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip'.
```

And yet, when I do <kbd>Right-click project</kbd> > <kbd>Gradle (STS)</kbd> > <kbd>Refresh All</kbd>, I just get this:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.882 secs
```

That's it.  **How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution to your problem, but you could trying removing STS and start using Eclipse BuildShip instead, which is the "official" support for Gradle in Eclipse IDE. BuildShip can be installed via the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration)